# Is a deadline ever given?

Tags: plot-explanation, nerve

In the film *Nerve* how do they decide when to announce the finals? Is it like a monthly thing? At the end of the month, the players with the most watchers get to compete in the finals?

I know it says it's a 24-hour game, but I just assumed that meant the game just continued all the time until the finals, then started all over again. Unless there's a new finals competition every single night and a new game every day that you have to keep entering.